# What is the dielectric constant of a star?

Tags: star, the-sun

1. What is the dielectric constant of a star, especially its corona? Is it of order 1 or is it quite large?
2. How much do "impurities" (elements other than H and He) affect the dielectric constant?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I've adjusted the wording a bit to better fit the site. Just fyi the answer will be different at radio frequencies and optical frequencies (visible light).

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a simple answer.  Plasma is a conductor, not a dielectric. The dielectric constant of a perfect conductor is infinite, but the highly rarified plasma in the corona isn't a perfect conductor. However this link http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node100.html may interest you.

Comment: Trying for the world's biggest capacitor here?  :-)  .   Now, as pointed out, plasmas conduct, but depending on the frequency band you're interested in, you may find some ranges where the plasma does hold energy rather than conduct it.

Comment: @JamesK there's nothing wrong with talking about the dielectric constant of conductors or other lossy materials; they are simply complex valued rather than real: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity#Complex_permittivity

Comment: @CarlWitthoft ditto.

Comment: @JamesK I found [Determination of the Dielectric Constant of a Plasma](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4684-0724-2_7) which gives a formula and might be helpful for the corona - I have to think of it. Do you think we could estimate all the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

#### Disclaimer

This not (yet) a full answer, since I only  focus on approaching part 1 of the question, namely the calculation of the dielectric constant of the corona.

#### Dielectric constant of the corona

The [Sun's corona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_corona)

> ... extends millions of kilometres into outer space and is most easily seen during a total solar eclipse [...]  measurements indicate strong ionization in the corona and a plasma temperature in excess of $1\,000\,000 {\rm K}$ much hotter than the surface of the Sun.

So let's dig a bit into plasma physics.

According to I. M. Podgornyi's article *[Determination of the Dielectric Constant of a Plasma](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4684-0724-2_7)*, in the absence of a magnetic field,  the dielectric constant $\varepsilon$ of a plasma can be written

$$ \varepsilon(\omega) = 1 - {{4\pi {e^2}n} \over {{m_e}{\omega ^2}}} \cdot {1 \over {1 - i{{{v_{col}}} \over \omega }}}$$

where $\omega$ is the angular frequency of the electromagnetic wave, $e =  1.60217662 \cdot 10^{-19} {\rm C}$ is the charge of an electron, $m_e = 511 {\rm keV} = 9.10938356 \cdot 10^{-31} {\rm kg}$ is the mass of an electron, $i$ the [imaginary unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number).

The frequency of collisions $ν_{col}$ with charged particles is given by

$${v_{col}} = {{{{2.10}^{ - 5}}{n_i}Z} \over {T_e^{3/2}\left( {\rm eV} \right)}}.$$

Here, we have $T_e \approx 80\ldots90 {\rm eV} = 10^6 {\rm K}$ the temperature of a plasma given in [electron volt](https://www.britannica.com/science/electron-volt), and (average?) $Z$ the charge number.

The next step towards an answer would be to figure out *all* parameters in this equation, in particular the *average* composition of the plasma (in terms $n$ and $Z$).

I did not yet manage that (yet), see also my question [Physical properties of the stellar corona?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/43429/typical-properties-of-the-corona-of-a-star?noredirect=1&lq=1)

#### References

The following publications might be helpful for determining $n_i$ and $Z$ for some or all consitutents of the coronal plasma:

- Mercier, Chambe: *[Electron density and temperature in the solar corona from multifrequency radio imaging](http://dx.doi.org/10.1051/0004-6361/201425540)* could help us with $n_e$.
- Bo Thidé: *[Radio Studies of Solar-Terrestrial Relationships](http://dx.doi.org/10.13140/RG.2.2.16990.54084)* shows a graph with the radially dependent plasma frequency of the solar corona at a given temperature.
- V. G. Ledenev, V. V. Tirsky, V. M. Tomozov: *[High-frequency waves in the solar coronal plasma](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252439478_High-frequency_waves_in_the_solar_coronal_plasma)* looks like saying something about $\omega$.

#### Related

- [What is the temperature of the solar atmosphere (the corona) and how is it measured?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/16674/what-is-the-temperature-of-the-solar-atmosphere-the-corona-and-how-is-it-measu/)

Comment: The solar corona is practically a collisionless plasma, so you can safely neglect the collision term here (even in the photosphere it should be negligible unless $\omega$ corresponds to radio waves).